# Reverse software engineering of "\" in Matlab

Tags: linear-algebra, matlab, gaussian-elimination, hermitian-matrices, cholesky-decomposition

23.3 Reverse software engineering of "". The following Matlab session records a sequence of tests of the elapsed times for various computations on a workstation manufactured in 1991. For each part, try to explain: (i) Why was this experiment carried out? (ii) Why did the result come out as it did? Your answers should refer to formulas from the text for flop counts. The Matlab queries help chol and help slash may help in your detective work.

```
%(a)
m = 200; Z = randn(m,m);
A = Z'*Z; b = randn(m,1);
tic; x = A\b; toc;
    elapsed_time = 1.0368
%(b)
tic; x = A\b; toc; 
    elapsed_time = 1.0303
%(c)
A2 = A; A2(m,1) = A2(m,1)/2;
tic; x = A2\b; toc;
    elapsed_time = 2.0361
%(d)
I = eye(m,m); emin = min(eig(A));
A3 = A - .9*emin*I;
tic; x = A3\b; toc;
    elapsed_time = 1.0362
%(e)
A4 = A - 1.1emin*I;
tic; x = A4\b; toc;
    elapsed_time = 2.9624
%(f)
A5 = triu(A);
tic; x = A5\b; toc;
    elapsed_time = 0.1261
%(g)
A6 = A5; A6(m,1) = A5(1,m);
tic; x = A6\b; toc;
    elapsed_time = 2.0012
```

Comment: Have you tried answering the question? What flop count formulas are given in the text? How might they apply here?

Comment: Maybe stackoverflow is more appropriate than math.se for this question?

Comment: Something says me that you want your homework completely done by us. But there will be no profit for you... A single (important) hint: taking $A=Z'*Z$ on line 3 implies that $A$ is in fact spd (symmetrical positive definite), therefore has real poitive eigenvalues; hence taking their min makes sense. You mention "chol" but I don't see it...